# Node.js no such file or directory

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install node/npm on a shared server for some testing. As its shared, I'm trying to install it in my own folder, ~/usr/bin

I've extracted the tar, and can see node/npm...

```
ls /kunden/homepages/myId/htdocs/usr/bin/nodejs/bin
node npm
```

If I echo $PATH (as I have modified .bashrc) I see the folder...

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/bin:/usr/local/msql/bin:/usr/games:.:/kunden/homepages/myId/htdocs/usr/bin/nodejs/bin
```

Now if I call npm or node, it 'finds' the node file, but then says

```
line 2: /kunden/homepages/myId/htdocs/usr/bin/nodejs/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

even if I put in the full path it says this, so it appears npm/node is looking for another file it can't find ?

I can see the file it says...

```
file /kunden/homepages/myId/htdocs/usr/bin/nodejs/bin/node 
/kunden/homepages/myId/htdocs/usr/bin/nodejs/bin/node: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

So I know in my path it can see node/npm fine. Is there some other file its looking for that I've missed ?

edit: If I run an strace, the debug output is...

```
execve("/kunden/homepages/myId/htdocs/usr/bin/nodejs/bin/node", ["/kunden/homepages/myId/htdocs/usr/bin/nodejs/bin/node"], [/* 36 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFL)                     = 0x8002 (flags     O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x55575000
_llseek(3, 0, 0xffc0b568, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
 write(3, "strace: exec: No such file or directory\n", 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
close(3)                                = 0
```

Comment: Can you call /kunden/homepages/myId/htdocs/usr/bin/nodejs/bin/node directly? Does it start the interpreter?

Comment: If I call that file direct, it comes up with the same error. If I 'ls' the file it displays the file, so I know its technically there. I'm unsure if its starting an interpreter, is there a way to check, as its just a binary file. Is it possible its trying to load an interpreter that isn't there ?

Comment: I've also added an strace to the original question.

Comment: Ok, I think its because its not really a 64bit server (even though it says x86_64 GNU/Linux ), maybe because its virtualised or something, it only really supports 32bit ? It seems to be recognised ok with the 32bit binaries

Comment: I would try modifying the permissions on the file to make sure it's executable. Its also possible you did something wrong when declaring the path you wanted to install it in.

Comment: Also, did you do any steps beyond untarring the files? You need to compile it in order to properly install it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the instructions if you're installing from source and not a package manager:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation#building-on-linux

Generally, when compiling from source, you end up doing something like this:

./configure && make && sudo make install

NOTE: you need to be careful here, because if you don't specify the path you want it to be installed to, it will default to /usr/lib && /usr/bin

Comment: Yep, I did try try that originally, but it came up with an out of memory error, so tried the compiled ver. Its all looking ok currently thanks since using 32bit bins (maybe its 32bit virtualised on a 64bit system or something, seems odd).